Using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit, show that $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x^3+2x^2-8x}{x-2}=12$
Using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit, show that
$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x^3+2x^2-8x}{x-2}=12$$
My first thought it to remove the singularity, by factorising out $(x-2)$ and getting
$$\lim_{x\to2}x(x+4)=12$$ $$|x(x+4) - 12|=0$$
From there, I would evaluate $δ$ for each value of $x$, and have an answer of the form $δ = \min(ε,ε)$, but I am unsure of how to proceed.

It helps to factorize $x(x+4)-12$ as $(x+6)(x-2)$ and try to bound the first factor $x+6$.

We want to prove that $\forall \varepsilon>0$ then $\exists \delta>0$ such that $|x-2|<\delta \Longrightarrow \left|\frac{x^3+2x^2-8x}{x-2}-12\right|<\varepsilon$.
First, we can rewrite the quantity in absolute values as follows:
$$\left|\frac{x^3+2x^2-8x}{x-2}-12\right|=\left|\frac{x^3+2x^2-20x+24}{x-2}\right|=(\ast)$$
Doing the euclidean division for polynomials, we obtain that:
$$(\ast)=|x^2+4x-12|=|(x+6)(x-2)|$$
Now, let $x\in (2-\delta,2+\delta)$, then:
$$|(x+6)(x-2)|=|x+6||x-2|<(8+\delta)\delta$$ This follows from $x\in (2-\delta,2+\delta)\Longrightarrow x+6\in (8-\delta,8+\delta)$.
If $\varepsilon\geq 1$, we can take $\displaystyle \delta=\frac{1}{9\varepsilon}$ and if $0<\varepsilon<1$, we can take $\displaystyle \delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{9}$.
In the first case, using that $\varepsilon \geq 1$, we have:
$$(8+\delta)\delta=\left(8+\frac{1}{9\varepsilon}\right)\frac{1}{9\varepsilon}=\frac{72\varepsilon+1}{81\varepsilon^2}\leq\frac{72\varepsilon+\varepsilon}{81\varepsilon^2}=\frac{73\varepsilon}{81\varepsilon^2}=\frac{73}{81\varepsilon}<\varepsilon$$
In the other case, using that $0<\varepsilon <1$, we have:
$$(8+\delta)\delta=\left(8+\frac{\varepsilon}{9}\right)\frac{\varepsilon}{9}=\frac{\varepsilon(72+\varepsilon)}{81}<\frac{73\varepsilon}{81}<\varepsilon$$

My first step when calculating a limit
is almost always to make the limit variable
go to zero.
In this case,
since
$x \to 2$,
this is the same as
$x-2 \to 0$.
Setting $y = x-2$,
$x = y+2$.
Replacing $x$ by $y+2$
in the expression,
$\begin{array}\\
L
&=\lim_{x\to2}\dfrac{x^3+2x^2-8x}{x-2}\\
&=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{(y+2)^3+2(y+2)^2-8(y+2)}{(y+2)-2}\\
&=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{y^3+3y^22+3y2^2+8+2(y^2+4y+4)-8y-16}{y}\\
&=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{y^3+6y^2+12y+8+2y^2+8y+8-8y-16}{y}\\
&=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{y^3+8y^2+12y}{y}\\
&=\lim_{y\to0}y^2+8y+12\\
&=12\\
\end{array}
$
To get the last limit,
if $|y| < 1$ then
$|y^2| <|y|< 1$
so
$|y^2+8y|
\lt |y+8y|
=|9y|$
so, to make
$|y^2+8y|
\lt \epsilon$
it is enough to take
$|y|<\min(1, \dfrac{\epsilon}{9})$.

Let $\varepsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.
Let $\delta:=\min\{\frac{\varepsilon}{9},1\}$.
$|x(x+4)-12|=|x(x+4)-2\times 6| = |x((x+4)-6)+(x-2)\cdot 6|$.
$|x((x+4)-6)+(x-2)\cdot 6|\leq |x||x-2|+6|x-2|$.
If $0<|x-2|<\delta$, then $|x|\leq |x-2|+2<\delta+2$.
So, if $0<|x-2|<\delta$, then $|x||x-2|+6|x-2|<(\delta+2)\delta+6\delta$.
$(\delta+2)\delta+6\delta=\delta^2+8\delta\leq\delta+8\delta=9\delta$.
$9\delta\leq 9\cdot\frac{\varepsilon}{9}=\varepsilon$.
